# Why is my session variable not persisting after server restart in Django

Tags: django, authentication, session, reddit, praw

I have a Django server handling Reddit authentication via PRAW and OAuth.
The following are the views I've written.

```
# unsaver/my_site/views.py

def default_view(request):
    if (request.session.get('refresh_token')):
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return redirect('/login')

def home_view(request):
    if (request.session.get('refresh_token')):
        code = request.session.get('code')
        rf = request.session.get('refresh_token')
        print(f'code is {code}\nrefresh_token is {rf}')
        reddit_authenticated = praw.Reddit("unsaver", refresh_token=rf, user_agent="unsaver for reddit")
        user_name = reddit_authenticated.user.me()
        return HttpResponse(user_name)
    else:
        return redirect('/login')


def login_view(request):
    if (request.session.get('refresh_token')):
        return redirect('/home')
    reddit = praw.Reddit("unsaver", user_agent="unsaver for reddit")
    authentication_uri = reddit.auth.url(["identity", "read", "save", "history"], random.randint(1, 99999), "permanent")
    template = loader.get_template('my_site/login.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'auth_url': authentication_uri}, request)) 

def authenticated(request):
    reddit = praw.Reddit("unsaver", user_agent="unsaver for reddit")
    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    refresh_token = reddit.auth.authorize(code)
    request.session['code'] = code
    request.session['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
    return redirect('home')
```

and following is its corresponding urls.py

```
# unsaver/my_site/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.default_view, name='default'),
    path('home', views.home_view, name="home"),
    path('login', views.login_view, name="login"),
    path('authenticated', views.authenticated, name="authenticated")
]
```

Initially when I start my server, it defaults to `localhost:8000/login`, after clicking on the login link and authenticating via Reddit it redirects to `localhost:8000/home` and then after subsequent reloads it redirects to home properly, even with multiple tabs. However, when I stop my server and run again, and click on the development server link given by Django, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` it takes me to the login page again, even when I have another tab with /home in it. Why does it ignore the session variables set in the first authentication and everytime I start the app by clicking the link, it redirects to login page, but if I type in the address it works fine. Does Django treat localhost and 127.0.0.1 differently?

I am new to Django and backend development so pardon me if my question sounds silly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on my testing, it looks like the answer to your question of "Does Django treat localhost and 127.0.0.1 differently?" is pretty much *yes*. Presumably Django is using cookies to store your session. Your browser will store cookies per host, and since `localhost` is different from `127.0.0.1`, cookies stored by one host name will not be accessible by the other.

Comment: Of course, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` resolve to the exact same thing, but technically they are different names.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. Should I keep this question now that it seems rather unnecessary?

Comment: I'm sure it will be useful to someone else — surely you're not the only person who has come across this or will come across it.